# Adiciona número em cada linha em c#

Tags: c#

Como remover a numeração dessa linha e então adicionar novamente em outro formato?

```
Input:
N0006 G90
N0007 G90
N0008 G92 X21.7301 Y88.9657
N0009 S555
N0010 D14
N0011 G42 G01 X22.0659 Y89.3015 
N0012 X22.4194 Y89.655 
N0013 (PATHSTART0)
```

Output(ficando assim):

```
N1 G90
N2 G90
N3 G92 X21.7301 Y88.9657
N4 S555
N5 D14
N6 G42 G01 X22.0659 Y89.3015 
N7 X22.4194 Y89.655 
N8 (PATHSTART0)
```

Eu teria que percorrer o text file certo? Mas como posso identificar a numeração do começo? Sendo que as vezes esses códigos chegam até 10mil linhas?

Comment: Então cara, nesse software https://www.machsupport.com/forum/index.php?action=dlattach;topic=27728.0;attach=38344 ele faz o que eu exatamente quero.. ele remove as linhas com N e depois adiciona novamente, o problema é que eu não tenho ideia de como fazer isso entende?

Comment: Olha não entendi muito bem, mas se for nesse padrão da pra você fazer um esquema pra remover tudo antes do espaço, e depois incluir tudo novamente incrementando de 1 em 1 na frente do N pra cada vez que passar no loop

Comment: DiegoAugusto.. Sim, isso mesmo, e como posso identificar um espaço em uma string e fazer isso ?

Comment: @stderr quase isso... as vezes as linhas pode chegar até 50mil entende? por isso estou tentando fazer o aqui o seguinte.. todos os valores antes do espaço ' ', eu queria deletar... você tem alguma ideia?

Comment: de assim: N0008 G92 X21.7301 Y88.9657
Ficando assim: G92 X21.7301 Y88.9657..... removendo o N0008 apenas na frente da string

Comment: Então.. assim que eu removesse o de antes.. eu iria percorrer o array de novo para add desse modo entende?

Comment: Deu certo aqui.. do jeito que eu queria... Muito obrigado pelo seu tempo!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu faria o seguinte:

Caso você tenha certeza que o padrão sempre inclui "N" no início:

```
string aux = linha.split(' ')[0];
string numeracao = aux.substring(1);
```

Caso você queria um inteiro:

```
string aux = linha.split(' ')[0];
int numeracao = Int32.Parse(aux.substring(1));
```

Caso você tenha um bloco de texto e queira dividir as linhas:

```
string[] separador = new string[] { "\r\n" };
string[] linhas = texto.Split(separador, StringSplitOptions.None);
foreach(string linha in linhas)
{
  string aux = linha.split(' ')[0];
  int numeracao = Int32.Parse(aux.substring(1));
}
```

Comment: E como faço para fazer o seguinte..

Deletar tudo o que tem antes do primeiro espaço ?

Comment: Eu usaria o método substring:

    string aux = linha.split(' ')[0];
    string semnumeracao = linha.substring(aux.lenght + 1);

Comment: Também deu certo aqui hehe... Obrigado!!!

Answer (score 3):

Para abrir o arquivo para leitura você pode usar o método [`File.OpenText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.file.opentext(v=vs.110).aspx).

O `File.OpenText` retorna um [`StreamReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx), considerando que seja um arquivo com muitas linhas, use o método [`StreamReader.ReadLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) para ler linha por linha num *loop*:

```
string linha;

using(var arquivo = File.OpenText("arquivo1.txt")) {
    while ((linha = arquivo.ReadLine()) != null) {
        // Use "linha" aqui ...
    }
}
```

Para obter a sequência antes do primeiro espaço, use o método [`String.IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string linha = "foo bar baz";
int indice = linha.IndexOf(" "); // 3. O número de caracteres antes do primeiro espaço
```

Com o índice dos caracteres que você quer remover, use o método [`String.Substring`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) para retornar a sequência a partir desse índice:

```
string linha = "foo bar baz";
int indice = linha.IndexOf(" ");

string outraLinha = "bar" + linha.Substring(indice);

Console.WriteLine(linha);      // foo bar baz
Console.WriteLine(outraLinha); // bar bar baz
```

No teu caso em específico, você pode aplicar assim:

```
using System.IO;
// ...

string linha;
int contador = 0;

using(var arquivo = File.OpenText("foobar.txt")) { // Abre o arquivo para leitura
    while ((linha = arquivo.ReadLine()) != null) { // Lê linha por linha
        int espaco = linha.IndexOf(" "); // Quantidade de caracteres antes do espaço
        contador++; // Incrementa o número da linha atual
        // Retorna os caracteres a partir do primeiro espaço
        string linhaIndexada = "N" + contador + linha.Substring(espaco); 

        // Use "linhaIndexada" aqui ...
    }
}
```

<kbd>[Ver **DEMO**](http://ideone.com/2PYU8n)</kbd>